# How do you add a third party reusable app to django and deploy in openshift?

Tags: python, django, openshift

I've built a web app using django deployed on openshift.  I'm trying to add the third party reusable app [markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux).  I've followed the install instructions (used pip) and it works fine on the localhost development server.

I've added 'markdown_deux' to my settings.py and tried it with and without a requirements.txt.  However, I still get a 500 error and from rhc tail the error "Import error: no module named markdown_deux".

I've tried restarting my app and resyncing the db but I'm still getting the same errors.  I've RTFM but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openshift has mechanisms to automatically check and add dependencies after each `git push`, depending on your application type. So you don't need to install dependencies manually.

For python applications modify the projects `setup.py`.

> Python application owners should modify `setup.py` in the root of the git repository with the list of dependencies that will be installed using `easy_install`.  The `setup.py` should look something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='YourAppName',
    version='1.0',
    description='OpenShift App',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='example@example.com',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    install_requires=['Django>=1.3', 'CloudMade'],
)
```

Read all details at the [Openshift Help Center](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202185484-Adding-dependencies-to-applications).

Answer (score 1):

You've used pip to install it locally, but you actually need to install it on your server as well. Usually you would do that by adding it to the `requirements.txt` file and ensuring that your deployment process includes running `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the server.